# Постановка запятых в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Во время нашего выступления с песней(,) в парадной форме(,) на последнем концерте(,) эта эмблема была пришита к моему рукаву.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны варианты оформления.

Я предлагаю:

*Во время нашего выступления с песней — в парадной форме, на последнем концерте — эта эмблема была пришита к моему рукаву.*

Comment: Очень правильный ответ, я тоже так думаю. Привет, привет!..  Редко нас навещаете, скучаем тут без вас.

Comment: Спасибо, Шерри! )))